# how to get specifics rows of 2d array returned by reading CSV file in java

Tags: java

This is data.csv file, now I want rows having classtype x (any number) and store those extarcted rows into new array, so if i have n classtype then i will have n new arrays.

```
age   sex  zipcode   classtype
21     m     23423   1
12     f     23133   2
23     m     32323   2
23     f     23211   1
```

Example: If I want to retrieve rows which have classtype 1 and store this values in a new 2d array. Then output should come like this:

```
array1={{21,m,23423,1},{23,f,23211,1}}
```

I have written the below code which gives me arrayList as output.

```
public class CsvParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : "data.csv");
            Map<String, List<String>> values = parseCsv(fr, "\\s,", true);
            System.out.println(values);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public static Map<String, List<String>> parseCsv(Reader reader, String separator, boolean hasHeader) throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<String>> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> columnNames = new LinkedList<String>();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    int numLines = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(line)) {
            if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(separator);
                if (tokens != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
                        if (numLines == 0) {
                            columnNames.add(hasHeader ? tokens[i] : ("row_"+i));
                        } else {
                            List<String> column = values.get(columnNames.get(i));
                            if (column == null) {
                                column = new LinkedList<String>();
                            }
                            column.add(tokens[i]);
                            values.put(columnNames.get(i), column);
                        }
                    }
                }
                ++numLines;
            }
        }
    }
    return values;
}
```

The ouput of this code is:

```
{age=[21,12,23,23],sex=[m,f,m,f],zipcode=[23423,23133,32323,23211],classtype=[1,2,2,1]}
```

I got few links, which says about grouping elements in "java collectors class", But dont whether that is useful.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-

Your help will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
String[][] allArrays = new String[50][]; //Set it to however many you need
String classType = "1";
int counter = 0;
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
while(s.hasNextLine()) {
    String row = s.nextLine();
    if (row.endsWith(classType) {
        allArrays[counter++] = row.split(","); //Adds the row, with each element being split by the comma
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel, you can use an existing library to dump the content of CSV file to a Java Collection. I usually use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to dump the contents of CSV file to `List<String[]>`. It has a one liner code to read all.

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
List<String[]> lines= reader.readAll();
```

Then iterate the list like this to do the grouping.

```
 Map<String, List<String[]>> values = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String[]>>();

 for(String[] line : lines){
    String key = line[4];

    if(values.get(key) == null){
        values.put(key, new ArrayList<String[]>());
    }

    values.get(key).add(line);
}

System.out.println(values);
```

Comment: It gives an error, readAll(), get and put methods not found an also
gives error like constructor CSVReader in class CSVReader cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: FileReader
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length


and one question, how m is serving the purspoe here.thank you for the reply @onepotato

Comment: `m` is the `value` in your existing code. Modified.

Comment: Your `values` should be `Map<String, List<String[]>>` not `Map<String, List<String>>` as 1 key (classtype) is associated with several record (`List<String[]>`)